# DOM onselect failing to work properly

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, textselection, onselect

I'm working with a text area defined as below:

`<textarea id="description"></textarea>`

I'm trying to detect when some text is selected by the user and the `onselect` seems perfect for this. It works perfectly on the w3schools example and I got it working as:

`<textarea id="description" onselect="alert('testing');"></textarea>`

But when I change this to my own function, nothing happens.

I have tried this using:
`document.getElementById("description").addEventListener("onselect", getSelection("description"));`

And that executes but on page load and does nothing when I select text.

I've just got simple stuff in the function to try and get it working, I've tested my action selection code and that's fine. I just can't get it to run an onselect event. Here is my testing `getSelection` function.

```
function getSelection(ele)
{
    var ele = document.getElementById(ele);

    var txt = "Text Selected";

    console.log(txt);
}
```

Any ideas? There seems to be very little information on `onselect` with most resources found by people thinking it's for select tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass a reference to the function, right now you just call the function right away using `()`. Also to add the event using `addEventListener` you have to use `select` instead of `onselect`.

```js
document.getElementById("description").addEventListener("select", getSelection);

function getSelection(event)
{
    var ele = event.target;

    var txt = "Text Selected";

    alert(txt);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="description"></textarea>
```